# Cannot see Flask endpoint in Google App Engine even though it should be there

Tags: flask, google-app-engine

This is the Flask `main.py`

```
@app.route("/routes", methods=["GET"])
def routes():
    return ['%s' % rule for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules()], 200


@app.route("/_ah/warmup", methods=["GET"])
def warmup():
    return {}, 200
```

for some reasons the warmup endpoint doesn't show up.
With the route endpoint I can verify it is correctly registered

```
(venv) ➜  app-engine git:(main) ✗ curl https://nutmeg-9099c.ew.r.appspot.com/routes -X GET           
["/static/<path:filename>","/matches/","/matches","/matches/<match_id>","/matches/<match_id>/ratings","/matches/<match_id>/ratings/to_vote","/matches","/payments/checkout","/users/<user_id>","/users/test","/users/<user_id>/tokens","/routes","/_ah/warmup"]
(venv) ➜  app-engine git:(main) ✗ curl https://nutmeg-9099c.ew.r.appspot.com/_ah/warmup -X GET

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Not Found</h1>
<h2>The requested URL <code>/_ah/warmup</code> was not found on this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
```

The endpoint correctly shows up in a local run

Comment: Did you [enable](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuring-warmup-requests?tab=python#enabling_warmup_requests) it in your ```app.yaml```?

Comment: how? I didn’t do it with the other endpoints

Answer (score 0):

Moving from comments to an answer

1. warmups are inbound_services. According to Google documentation

> Applications must enable those services before it can receive inbound requests. You can enable the service for a Python 2 app by including an inbound_services section in the app.yaml file.

**Note:** The above talks about a Python 2 App but it should apply to Python 3 too

2. Based on bullet 1, try enabling the service. See how to do it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuring-warmup-requests?tab=python#enabling_warmup_requests)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @NoCommandLine you need to enable the warmup request.

You must add the following code to your App Engine app.yaml file to guarantee that the warmup endpoint is correctly configured:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: auto
```

In your `app.yaml` file, make sure that the above code is positioned at the very top of the handlers section.
Try redeploying your application to App Engine by using the following command if the previously mentioned fix doesn't work:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

This should assist to fix any configuration issues that might be blocking the warmup endpoint from being detected because it will rebuild and reinstall your application to App Engine.

Reference: [Enabling warmup request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuring-warmup-requests?tab=python#enabling_warmup_requests)